# How to write a parameterized test in spring boot tests?

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

I am writting functional automation tests(web services) for my application.  As a part of my JSON request, I need to pass Product, Location, Customer and etc..

My application business logic will change based on the request parameters.

Sample Request

```
        {
        "Prodcut": [{
            "Item": String,
            "dep": Number,
            "Price": Number,
            "quantityType": Number,
            "discountAccepted": Boolean,
            "depGrpNo": Number,
            "adjustment": {
                "extValues": Number,
                "qtyType": Number
            }
        }]
        "Location": [{
            "LocName": String,
            "depName": String,
            "Address": String,
            "LOCType": String
        }]
    }
```

I need to changes each value with the JSON. How to write a parameterization test for these scenarios. I am expecting around 1000 test cases for this.

Comment: Do you have 1000 JSON files or do you want to set the values programmatically?

Comment: I want to set the values programmatically based on the scenario. Maintenance is very high If I have 1000 Json files.

Comment: So then you have to write the code to do that. Or what kind of solution do you expect?

Comment: I am planning to write a code for this using Junit5

Comment: So then I don't understand your question. You simply have create this JSON in a loop of 1000

Comment: In Junit5, We have different methods to achieve parameterizatoin. But not able to figure out which one is suites better for this. Looking for a better solution

Comment: When I am accessing the rest API. I need to send this Json ]as a request. So Based on the scenario data will change. This is the sample Json, but in future it may change and need to update 100 of parameters.